# Weird results with post incrementing

Tags: post-increment, pre-increment

Ok, I thought i knew about post-incrementing and pre-incrementing but...

Funny /Weird /How? /Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a = 0;

   printf(" A++ - %d \n A++ - %d \n A++ - %d \n A++ - %d", a++, a++, a++, a++);
}
```

Without compiling it, what would you say the result is (what values would A++ get)?

---

And what about this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a = 0;

   printf(" A++ - %d \n A++ - %d \n A++ - %d \n A++ - %d", a++, a++, a++, ++a);
}
```

??

Comment: undefined - there are several questions around this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)